# Bayesian curve fitting model

Tags: math, machine-learning, probability, bayesian, pattern-recognition

With respect to bayesian curve fitting, eq 1.68 of Bishop - Pattern recognition

How is the following result derived :

p(t|x, **x**, **t**) = Integration{ p(t|x, **w**)p(**w**|**x**, **t**) } dw

Comment: this question is pretty far from being self contained. you should define all the symbols in the above equation rather than just post a reference to some book. there are most likely several ways that it can be derived.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets just consider a simpler case using the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).
If w1, w2 are disjoint events then

```
p(A) = p(A|w1) p(w1) + p(A|w2) p(w2)
```

we can extend this to any number of items

```
p(A) = sum_{wi} p(A|wi) p(wi)
```

or indeed take the limit

```
p(A) = int_{w} p(A|w) p(w) dw
```

We can make A depend on another independent event B that the w's might depend on

```
p(A|B) = int_{w} p(A|w) p(w|B) dw
```

or an event C which the w's do not depend on

```
p(A|B,C) = = int_{w} p(A|w,C) p(w|B) dw
```

which is just your formula with different variables.

Comment: Note: the first line is valid provided that A is contained in the union of w1 and w2, and similarly, the second and third lines assume that A is contained in the union of the w's on the right hand side. In the context of eq. 1.68 in Bishop this is indeed the case, as he is integrating over all possible values of w.

Comment: Also, in the second sentence, "independent events" should be "disjoint events" (equivalently, "mutually exclusive events").